# PHP - require_once seems to be including files multiple times and causing errors

Tags: php, require-once

In my PHP app, I have several calls to `require_once`. On my development PC this works fine and doesn't try to include the same file multiple times. However when I moved it to my production server I'm getting an error

> cannot redeclare class myClass

After searching through the code I've found that this happens just after a call to `require_once`, so it must be that which is causing it.

I've searched through the entire project and this class is definitely only declared in one file, and it's only ever included through `require_once`. Is there some weird PHP config that would make `require_once` behave differently on the production server?

Thanks

Comment: `require_once` will check if the *file* has been included not if the *class* has been defined.

Comment: yes, maybe you have defined the same class in 2 different files

Comment: I definitely haven't done that - I have checked the whole project - this class is only defined in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following at the top of your included class file:

```
if( class_exists( "<yourclassname>"))
{
throw new Exception("Class already defined");
}
```

You will now receive a clear error message where the class is re-called.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this obnoxious problem can be caused by one of two things of which I'm aware:

symlinks; if loading from a file and a symlink pointing to the file

on OS X (and maybe Windows), the filenames are case-insensitive; PHP require_once is not

This had me confused for several hours today.  I usually work in Linux, but I was forced onto a Mac where this becomes a problem.